# Pandas apply in 2 columns and substitute them in one line

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, kaggle

I'm trying to improve the performance of my code and I want to tokenize 2 columns of a dataframe and I had it like this

```
submission_df['question1'] = submission_df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['question1']), axis=1)
submission_df['question2'] = submission_df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['question2']), axis=1)
```

And I thought maybe I could merge them in one line and that way I'll only iterate once over all the rows(2 million), so I thought something like this

```
submission_df['question1'],submission_df['question2'] = submission_df.apply
    (lambda row: 
     (nltk.word_tokenize(row['question1']),
      nltk.word_tokenize(row['question2'])), axis=1)
```

but didn't work, and maybe there are other ways to improve it instead of using the apply method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `apply` for the selected columns with astype(str) i.e

```
submission_df[['question1','question2']]=submission_df[['question1','question2']].astype(str).apply(lambda row: [nltk.word_tokenize(row['question1']),nltk.word_tokenize(row['question2'])], axis=1)
```

Example :

```
import nltk
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Nice to meet you ","Nice to meet you ","Nice to meet you ",8,9,10],"B":[7,6,7,"Nice to meet you ","Nice to meet you ","Nice to meet you "]})
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].astype(str).apply(lambda row: [nltk.word_tokenize(row['A']),nltk.word_tokenize(row['B'])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                          A                      B
0  [Nice, to, meet, you]                    [7]
1  [Nice, to, meet, you]                    [6]
2  [Nice, to, meet, you]                    [7]
3                    [8]  [Nice, to, meet, you]
4                    [9]  [Nice, to, meet, you]
5                   [10]  [Nice, to, meet, you]
```

Comment: it gives an error: TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index question1'). I suppose it is because the nltk.word_tokenize(text) needs to receive the text in which you want to apply the tokenizer.

Comment: @set92 Updated my answer hope it helps.

Comment: It seems it does somethink, but the original 2 lines takes 134s and this one 263s, so for now I'll take with the original lines